# What's the right way to pronounce "Louis"?

Tags: pronunciation, names, silent-letters

The name of the comedian [Louis C.K.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_C.K.) is pronounced LU-EE-SEE-KAY.

Is the **S** pronounced as a part of the given name "Louis", or just the first constant of the of the letter **C**?

Is there a canonical way to pronounce the English name "Louis", or is the pronunciation dependent in geographic location or origin?

Credit: [this tweet](https://twitter.com/HaAlmaEfronit/status/372056943432458240) (Hebrew).

Comment: Everyone gets to spell and pronounce their own name as they please - (signed) Robert (pronounced sha-zam')

Comment: Normally the *English* Louis is pronounced the same as the French one, because there is also a name Lewis. American Louises may differ. (What's the plural of Louis?)

Comment: Incidentally, the tweet you cite is protected (we can't see it).

Comment: @AndrewLeach, and how do you separate the plural of ‘Louis’ from the plural of ‘Louise’?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I’ve never met a Louis who wasn’t pronounced Lewis in English.

Comment: @tchrist He distinguished between *English* & American Louises. I presume that by *English*, he meant "from England" - or possibly "British" (tho' I doubt there would be many Welsh, Scottish or Irish Louises).

Comment: The correct way to pronounce it is the way Louis pronounces it.

Comment: Tangentially related amusing reading: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names are a bit tricky to give 'pronunciation' advice on, because anyone can choose to pronounce their name in any way they see fit.

I have heard two pronunciations used for this name.  "LU-EE", as you've shown, and "LU-ISS".

The first one is the traditional french pronunciation, while the second is of English origin.

For more information: http://www.behindthename.com/name/louis

Comment: I would say there are three pronunciations: /ˈluːi/, /luːˈi(ː)/, and /ˈluːis/. Of these, the second is quite rare, but there are non-French guys named Louis who pronounce their name with final stress.

Comment: When you say "the second is of English origin" are you referring to the English language, or to England?

Comment: You might say there are two pronunciations for "Louis": "Lewis" and "Louie"

Answer (score 3):

The English pronunciation of the *s* in *Louis* was reinforced during the 1600s and 1700s by frequent respelling of the French name *Louis* as *Lewis*. An Ngram chart for the years 1600 through 2005 shows that "King Lewis" (blue line) was the preferred spelling over "King Louis" until about 1770:

[image]

Here is a typical instance of "King Lewis" from "[The Life and Reign of King Henry the Second](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Co-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22king+lewis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAmoVChMIta7x0q6bxwIVBTeICh07TAW0#v=onepage&q=%22king%20lewis%22&f=false)," in *Chronicle of the Kings of England: With Additions* (1670):

> With which words of King *Lewis*, the young King *Henry* was set a float, and from that time forward, stuck not openly to oppose his Father. Whereof his Father having intelligence, sent messengers to King *Lewis*, desiring him from the King their Master, to be a means to bring his Son to more moderation. But King *Lewis* hearing the Embassadours name their Master King, with an angry countenance said unto them ; What mean you by this to call him King, who hath passed his Kingdom over to his Son? and with this answer sent them away.

The spelling *Lewis* for *Louis* became very rare after the 1760s, but it survived until then in such forms as this (translated) title of a history by Voltaire: [*The Universal History & State of All Nations From the Time of Charlemain to Lewis XIV*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xLUvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=%22king+lewis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCDgUahUKEwisn5KCsZvHAhWUSogKHfOZDPg#v=onepage&q=%22king%20lewis%22&f=false) (1758).

Answer (score 1):

His name is Louis like Lewis and his nickname is Louie.

Comment: Do you have a source? (Either from Louis C.K. himself, or for someone who ought to know about it.)

Comment: OK, now how do you pronounce "Louisville"?

Comment: @hot licks.... It's been a while since this post, but asking someone how they pronounce Louisville isn't a good test. :P. Officially, it's named after king Louis, so it is loo-ey-ville. But any local will call it lull-vull

Comment: @MikeChristiansen - I think it could be an instructive exercise.  (How do they pronounce it in Colorado?)